# Javascript simple mathematics what i dont understand ( beginner )

Tags: javascript

my mission is :  write numbers 1-100. if the number can divide with 3 then write it into the console next to the number  " it can be divided with 3 ". if the number is 5 also write it into the console next to the number " it can be divided with 5 " and if it cant be divided with 3 also with 5 just leave it and write nothing

```
for (var listing=1;listing<=30;listing++){
  if (listing % 3 != 0) {
    console.log(" A(z) " + listing + "  ");
  } else if (listing % 5 == 0) {
    console.log(" A(z) " + listing + " it can be divided with 3 and 5 ");
  } else if (listing % 3 == 0){
    console.log(" A(z) " + listing + " it can be divided with 3  ");
  }
}
```

if the number can divided by both of them its okay. but i dont know the command for write it " it can be divided by 5 " if the number can be divided by five.
because this is the last thing what cant be showed please help

Comment: Google for ["FizzBuzz"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1MSIM_enUS679US679&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=fizzbuzz+program).

Comment: @csm_dev Ha I forgot that was a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want. Does this help you?

```js
for (var listing = 1; listing <= 100; listing++) {
 if (listing % 3 != 0 && listing % 5 != 0) {
  console.log(" A(z) " + listing + "  ");
  
 } else if (listing % 3 == 0 && listing % 5 == 0) {
  console.log(" A(z) " + listing + " it can be divided with 3 and 5  ");
  
 } else if (listing % 3 == 0) {
  console.log(" A(z) " + listing + " it can be divided with 3 ");
  
 } else if (listing % 5 == 0) {
  console.log(" A(z) " + listing + " it can be divided with 5  ");
  
 }

}
```

Comment: exactly :D:D:D thanks man :) i didn't know that exists " && "

Comment: @coolice No worries :) It means "and". Try doing some Javascript tutorials and you'll see it pretty soon. Don't forget to accept this as the correct answer if this does what you wanted.

Comment: it says i have to wait for mark it :D btw. the last else if doesn't work :/ i mean if at number 15 it only says " it can be divided by 5 " but it can be divided by 3 and the last else if doesnt say bot of them. any idea?

Comment: @coolice Ah right, I worked out why and edited my answer. The reason is that if the number (say, 15) was divisible by 3 and 5, it would get as far as the `else if (listing % 5 == 0)` and then since that condition was true, it wouldn't continue to any of the other elseifs. I just rearranged the code so that it checks matching nothing, matching 3 and 5, matching only 3, and finally matching only 5.